# Disable dragging an image from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I need to put an image in my page. I want to disable dragging of that image. I am trying lot of things but no help. Can somebody help me out ?

I don't want to keep that image as a background-image because I am resizing the image.

Comment: @AgentConundrum - There is no problem for me if the user saves and does whatever he wants. My only requirement is to not to drag that image.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I tried myself and found this is working.

```
$("img").mousedown(function(){
    return false;
});
```

I am sure this disables dragging of all the images. Not sure it effects something else.

Comment: Ah! You should've mentioned you were using jQuery/could use jQuery. +1 for using jQuery.

Comment: @alex - I am sorry. I was trying it my self. And I am not sure it effects something else.

Comment: you are fine! No, as far as I know, doing what you have here should not have any negative effects on anything else.

Comment: What if the image is wrapped inside an `<a>` tag? Then if the user clicks the image, the link wouldn't get clicked.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, this also works in GWT with a `      event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: `$('img').mousedown(false)` shorter. And @SeinopSys What browser you're using? It still works at least for me (FF v59.0.2). Didn't test with other browsers though but here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/prz0tqr3/) for test.

Comment: All the time wasted on other attempts that failed, THIS SOLUTION WORKS!!!

Answer (score 297):

You can like this...

```
document.getElementById('my-image').ondragstart = function() { return false; };
```

[See it working (or not working, rather)](http://jsbin.com/ogibe3/edit)

It seems you are using jQuery.

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: @alex - The purpose of not have image dragging is not stealing the image. The purpose is completely different. I am making that image as sortable and droppable. So it takes a long time to explain it.

Comment: @alex - Is ondragstart is browser independent ?

Comment: @Multiplexer It seems to be except for < Firefox 3.5

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Try `$(document)` instead of `$(window)`

Comment: I just worked out you can simplify the jQuery to: `$('img').on('dragstart', false);`

Comment: @rybo111 Perhaps you could, but I would avoid it as a) AFAIK it's not documented by jQuery and b) confusing to what it would actually be doing.

Comment: @alex Under handler: [`The value false is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return false.`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @AdamMerrifield Well there you go. One thing to note is it will prevent propagation too, which could be a problem.

Answer (score 216):

CSS only solution: use `pointer-events: none`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: But this lead to the weird selection effect in FF atleast. Better still return false;

Comment: it is not used when image as link.

Comment: Looks like this won't work in IE (any version) see: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: Also a *CSS only* solution: place an element *over* the `img`.

Comment: @Shane No, it's not! Some of us still need to support IE9 and worse.

Comment: Hehe, gotcha @Lego.  Curse you older IE!  :)

Comment: This forces the cursor type to `cursor: default` :'(

Comment: -1 ! This should be used to prevent ALL ponter events (including dragging over, like when you want to upload an image). Use javascript solution isntead!

Comment: For my problem (i wanted no interaction at all in a div) this worked for modern browsers

Comment: This prevents any interaction, not just  drag-drop

Comment: @alex: how do you place an element over it using css-only??!

Answer (score 205):

just add draggable="false" to your image tag:

```
<img draggable="false" src="image.png">
```

IE8 and under doesn't support however.

Answer (score 50):

```
window.ondragstart = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: +1 Don't understand the downvotes. It's not the ultimate solution, while it prevents dragging all, not only a special image. But it shows the right direction(and I think it was the first answer which does it)

Comment: @DrMolle It may have been in response to the (since deleted) comments left by Steve on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4211930/edit).

Comment: Remember that sometimes people will drag a link to their bookmarks bar -- this solution would remove this ability.

Comment: Shows how to do it, sure, but it prevents dragging everything which is eh.. Upvote anyway, for showing how to do it.

Answer (score 45):

simplest cross browser solution is

```
<img draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;" src="..." />
```

problem with

```
img {
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 user-drag: none;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

is that it is not working in firefox

Comment: Demonstrator found at https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/x2fs8Lqa/4/

Answer (score 26):

```
img {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

I used it on my website at http://www.namdevmatrimony.in/
It's works like a magic!!! :)

Comment: It's draggable in firefox

Answer (score 21):

You can use inline code for this

```html
<img draggable="false" src="http://www.ourkanpur.com/images/logo.png">
```

And the second option is use external or on-page css

```css
img {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.ourkanpur.com/images/logo.png">
```

**Both are Working Correctly** 
I m using external css on this site [(Click Here)](http://www.ourkanpur.com/)

Comment: Neither of these seem to work on Firefox (using Mac Firefox 69)

Answer (score 16):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283142/932282); in Chrome and Safari you can use the following style to disable the default dragging:

```
-webkit-user-drag: auto | element | none;
```

You could try [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) for Firefox and IE(10+):

```
-moz-user-select: none | text | all | element
-ms-user-select: none | text | all | element
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add the following to each image you don't want to be draggable, (inside the `img` tag):

```
onmousedown="return false;"
```

e.g.

```
img src="Koala.jpg" onmousedown="return false;"
```

Answer (score 13):

Directly use this: `ondragstart="return false;"` in your image tag.

```
<img src="http://image-example.png" ondragstart="return false;"/>
```

If you have multiple images, wrapped on a `<div>` tag:

```
<div ondragstart="return false;">
   <img src="image1.png"/>
   <img scr="image2.png"/>
</div>
```

Works in all major browsers.

Answer (score 11):

This code does exactly what you want. It prevents the image from dragging while allowing any other actions that depend on the event.

```
$("img").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Since my images were created using ajax, and therefore not available on windows.load.

`$("#page").delegate('img', 'dragstart', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });`

This way I can control which section blocks the behavior, it only uses one event binding and it works for future ajax created images without having to do anything.

With jQuery new `on` binding:

`$('#page').on('dragstart', 'img', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });`
(thanks @ialphan)

Comment: Using .on it will be like this: $(document).on('dragstart','img',function(e){e.preventDefault();});

Comment: This is the correct solution. One event binding for unlimited `img` elements, present or future. Least intensive, most robust.

Answer (score 8):

```
<img draggable="false" src="images/testimg1.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Great solution, had one small issue with conflicts,
If anyone else has conflict from other js library simply enable no conflict like so.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();$j('img').bind('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 4):

Well I don't know if the answers in here have helped everyone or not, but here's a simple inline CSS trick which would definitely help you to disable dragging and selecting texts on a HTML page.

On your `<body>` tag add `ondragstart="return false"`. This will disable dragging of images. But if you also want to disable text selection then add `onselectstart="return false"`.

The code will look like this: `<body ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false">`

Answer (score 4):

You may consider my solution the best. Most of answers are not compatible with old browsers like IE8 since **e.preventDefault()** wont be supported as well as **ondragstart** event. To do it cross browser compatible you have to block **mousemove** event for this image. See example below:

**jQuery**

```
$("#my_image").mousemove( function(e) { return false } ); // fix for IE
$("#my_image").attr("draggable", false); // disable dragging from attribute
```

**without jQuery**

```
var my_image = document.getElementById("my_image");
my_image.setAttribute("draggable", false);

if (my_image.addEventListener) {
   my_image.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) { return false });
} else if (my_image.attachEvent) {
   my_image.attachEvent("onmousemove", function(e) { return false });
}
```

tested and worked even for IE8

Answer (score 4):

Set the following CSS properties to the image:

```
user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

Comment: Does not seem to work on Firefox (using Mac Firefox 69)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('dragstart drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

You can replace the *body* selector with any other container that children you want to prevent from being dragged and dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is possible, and the other answers posted are perfectly valid, but you could take a brute force approach and prevent the default behavior of `mousedown` on images. Which, is to start dragging the image.

Something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {  
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');   
    for (var i = 0; img = images[i++];) {    
        img.ondragstart = function() { return false; };
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('#yourImageId').addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Works in this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HbAbJkF0PVLIMjTmEZml

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple:

`<body oncontextmenu="return false"/>` - disable right-click
   `<body ondragstart="return false"/>` - disable mouse dragging
   `<body ondrop="return false"/>` - disable mouse drop

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way to do it with `JQuery`

```
$("body").on('mousedown','img',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

the **`on`** function attachs an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements

Comment: Demonstrator found at https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/x2fs8Lqa/7/

Answer (score 0):

I did the css properties shown here as well as monitor ondragstart with the following javascript:

```
handleDragStart: function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.nodeName.match(/^(IMG|DIV|SPAN|A)$/i)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `e.preventDefault()`. Examples:

Pure HTML:

```html
<img
  src={item.icon}
  onmousedown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }}
/>
```

React

```html
<img
  src={item.icon}
  onMouseDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }}
/>
```

Comment: How is that "pure" HTML? It uses javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Stealing from my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283211/1408137),  just add a completely transparent element of the same size over the image.  When you resize your image, be sure to resize the element.

This should work for most browsers, even older ones.