# Swipe, swipeleft, swiperight events do not trigger on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want use jQuery mobile's [swiperight event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/) in combination with an image, which doesn't seem to function.

HTML:

```
<div id="one"><img src="http://jquerymobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/jquery-mobile-logo-03.png"/></div>
<div id="two">works</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#one").on("swiperight", function() {
    alert("does not work");
});
$("#two").on("swiperight", function() {
    alert("works");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CbEQ/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure only desktop browser have this issue as mobile browsers usually don't drag images on swipe.

The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211930/1140682) prevents dragging your image in all browsers:

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

So here is your new working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4CbEQ/1/

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent image dragging, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SgUZK/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){   
    $('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });

    $("#one").on("swiperight", function() {
        alert("does not work");
    });
    $("#two").on("swiperight", function() {
        alert("works");
    });
});
```