# jQuery UI Draggable - how to prevent browser image dragging (to desktop)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm at a loss here. I have a draggable app working very well that is based on jQuery UI draggable. Its doing everything I want it to. However, when I go to drag an image, the native browser function that allows me to drag and drop an image to my desktop or another browser tab always means that I have to click the image and drag it a bit, then let it go, and then click and drag again in order to get the draggable going. I know I've seen sites where I can drag an image without this happening.

[Here is a brief video showing you what is happening](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119908/vid.mov) - in the video, on the first click when the drag enabler turns green I grab and shake the image I am dragging all over. This is the browser behavior where I can drop this image on my desktop and also onto the tab bar to open it in a new tab. The second time I click the image it slides up and down, constrained to the vertical axis only, as defined in the function call.

[I've tried just about everything on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page) and others like it, and all of those things tend to disable any dragging of the image at all including how I want it to drag. I've also added div's around each image and nothing changes. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
//Accessories dragging
var $drag_contain = $('#current_build');
$(document).on('drag', '.drag', function(ev,dd) {
    $(this).draggable({
        disabled: false,
        axis: "y",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //when dragging is done, remove ability to drag
            $(this).css('z-index','5').removeClass('drag').draggable('disable');
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
  <div id="current_build">
<div class="10117" style="z-index:2;top:0px;left:0px;"><img src=
"/assets/images/config_combos_sized/bas_18invhrcfootpedal.png" /></div>

<div class="10124" style="z-index:3;top:0px;left:0px;"><img src=
"/assets/images/config_combos_sized/col_47_5inshortvhrc.png" /></div>

<div class="10356" style="z-index:1;top:0px;left:0px;"><img src=
"/assets/images/config_combos_sized/cas_4intwin_18invhrc.png" /></div>

<div class="10362" style="z-index:4;top:-27px;left:0px;"><img src=
"/assets/images/config_combos_sized/dm_dualmonitormount.png" /></div>

<div class="10374" style="z-index:5;top:34px;left:0px;"><img src=
"/assets/images/config_combos_sized/acc_dividedutilitybin.png" /></div>
```

Obviously I have div's around the images at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was calling draggle enable and disable a few too many times based on other interactions. A refactoring of my events fixed this up.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<div style="background: url('/assets/images/config_combos_sized/bas_18invhrcfootpedal.png') no-repeat;"></div>
```

Then you can drag it without worrying about the browser behavior.