# programmatically stop while dragging a HTML element

Tags: html

I have an object which can be dragged and dropped on the screen by a user, and its position is updated to other users in real-time via websocket.
If user1 grabs the object and then user2 grabs it, I want to programmatically stop user1 drag, how do I do it?Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us some code please?

Comment: @jsve the question can be simplified as: if a user is dragging an HTML object, how can I stop that action programmatically in Javascript? The code is quite long but if this doesn't help explain my question, I'll post it then.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your simplification of your question, it seems that [this stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page) may be of use to you.