# Prevent images from moving (with a mouse) while browsing

Tags: css, web

When I am finished with the page. When its done. I want somehow to lock the images (for ex. header logo layer - try it out: http://www.lipanska.cz/ move with the header text EWITA). On the other side at https://www.google.com the logo is locked and I cant move with it.

How could i lock them?
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26970441/3426774

^^ Here is the best answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Google uses a `div` with a `background-image` and the other page is using an `img` tag. The latter makes it dragable with the mouse cursor.
You can also prevent dragging with any tag as discussed here:
[Disable dragging an image from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use Background Images.

demo:

```css
div{
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></img>
```

You cannot move first image, however you can move the second one.