# How can I prevent drag and drop images in a react app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

We got [how to prevent drag drop image with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page) with `$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });` but I want to achieve the same in a react app, and without jquery. How can I do this ? a) locally (image per image) b) globally (for all images of the react app)

I still want to keep control over other interactions, so `img { pointer-events: none; }` is not a solution.

The goal is to prevent saving image through drag and drop.

Comment: @ArmanCharan Yes, it (`draggable="false"`) works for images for which `onClick={}` is doing something, but for the others, it works when I do this directly, **but when I click once, the image is kind of selected and then I can drag it for unknown reason**.

Comment: As @ArmanCharan mentioned, adding a draggable attribute works as you can see for yourself here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r6p4jyko4
But it'll be really helpful if you could show us what you have tried till now.
Apologies if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ShishirAnshuman As I commented, I see the same specific problem with your quoted example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `onDragStart`:

```
onDragStart={this.preventDragHandler}
```

And the handler:

```
preventDragHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer your syntax to `preventDragHandler(e) {e.preventDefault();}` ?

Comment: To avoid `this` binding.

Comment: Interesting. And that's only making it lighter to write ?

Comment: This doesn't compile (webpack), I got `Unexpected token` on the first = after `preventDragHandler`

Answer (score 9):

For apps using HTML5, setting `draggable={false}` in react should accomplish this as well. It will wind up setting the [HTML5 draggable attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp) to "false".

Another option would be to just use CSS and set `pointer-events: none;` on the image.