# How can I disable the image dragging efect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a carousel which is working great, the only problem is that when I drag the image, a ghosting replica hovers above the image. This also happens when I drag the image container.

I tried with `draggable="false"` and also with `user-select: none !important;` but none of them worked.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: just use `pointer-events: none;` on `img`

Comment: you can also override drag action

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211936/3459770

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable dragging an image from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS

```css
img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS selector `pointer-events`. So, give it the style `pointer-events: none;`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)'s some more documentation on that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('drag').ondragstart = function() { return false; };
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2016999/pexels-photo-2016999.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" id="drag" />
```

Comment: if i use this I can't swipe through the images anymore

Comment: @MedveTheFab, implement the swipe on a parent element, not on the image itself