# Disable dragging of image in entire project HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

I want to disable dragging of ***all the images in my project*** which has a large amount of images. The results that I found on web was to disable a particular image. Putting `draggable="false"` inside every image tag would take a lot of time. So I want a solution to disable them together.

I was successful to disable dragging with this code but it's still draggable in Firefox .

```
img {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

I've already gone through [Disable dragging an image from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page) but found no answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `ondragstart` attribute to single image & `return false`.

If you want to address multiple images

```
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    imgs[i].setAttribute("ondragstart", "return false")
}
```

Note from React [Synthetic events](http://As%20of%20v0.14,%20returning%20false%20from%20an%20event%20handler%20will%20no%20longer%20stop%20event%20propagation.%20Instead,%20e.stopPropagation()%20or%20e.preventDefault()%20should%20be%20triggered%20manually,%20as%20appropriate.)

> As of v0.14, returning false from an event handler will no longer stop event propagation. Instead, e.stopPropagation() or e.preventDefault() should be triggered manually, as appropriate.

So you need add to each image.

`<img src={source} onDragStart={e => e.preventDefault()} />`

Comment: This answer was more efficient than others. It helped me to solve the issue. I hope the question was not very silly for you.

Comment: How to implement this in REACT ?

Comment: @Kundan you removed tag of accepted answer to ask how to do it in React? it's not fair, even React word is not mentioned in your question :D

Comment: But if you think I removed it due to I asked it for REACT, then I'm putting it back. I hope you liked my question. If yes do give a upvote.

Answer (score 1):

For specific image you can do something like this, it will work on all `browsers`

```html
<!-- right image (dragging disabled) -->
<img src="https://contribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/gfg-39.png" onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
```

If you want all of your images non draggable in all browsers including `firefox` then few lines of javascript can do that for you!

```js
// register onLoad event with anonymous function
window.onload = function(e) {
  var evt = e || window.event, // define event (cross browser)
    imgs, // images collection
    i; // used in local loop
  // if preventDefault exists, then define onmousedown event handlers
  if (evt.preventDefault) {
    // collect all images on the page
    imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    // loop through fetched images
    for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
      // and define onmousedown event handler
      imgs[i].onmousedown = disableDragging;
    }
  }
};

// disable image dragging
function disableDragging(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<img src="https://contribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/gfg-39.png">

<img src="https://contribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/gfg-39.png">

<img src="https://contribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/gfg-39.png">
```